# unable to reprouce with selenium actions (latest release) somethign which is working well in my browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests

this is my first question and I pray to have sometthing to help me. I search a lot about selenium webdriver actions ans I didn't find anything.

I want to test that I add a new class to the element I drag (in my case an image)

```
    const origine = await browser.findElement(By.id('strategicMap'));
    const zone2place = await browser.findElement(By.id('Cross1'));
    const unit2move = await browser.findElement(By.name("1st Patrol"));

    await browser.actions({async:true})
                    .move({origin:unit2move})
                    .press()
                    .perform();

   console.log(await browser.findElement(By.id('dialogZone')).getAttribute('innerHTML'));

   await browser.actions({async:true})
         .move({origin:origine,x:50})
         .perform();

   console.log(await browser.findElement(By.id('dialogZone')).getAttribute('innerHTML'));
   console.log(await unit2move.getAttribute('class'));
```

As you can see I began by moving to the center of my img and press left mouse button.

the first console log give x:755, y:546 (center of my img) prooving that my onmousemove event is correctly fired and clientX and ClientY stored in the dialog div. the class for my img is the .unit class. the same in any browser as I haven't moved the drag startevent didn't fired yet.

then I do a move.
the second console.log give X:454 and y: 332 ... so me mouse did a move but the class rmain wit only the .unit class instead of "unit dragged" in the browser.

I try to use unit2move as move origine but I have an error MoveTergetOutBounds Error ...

I try to use the webElement behin zone2place (it's an area) with Id 'Cross1' but the mouse move to a wrong place (x:48 et Y: 64 instead of 746, 472)

any one can give me any advice to reproduce the good mouse actions ?

Comment: probably something wrong with Chrome as everything works for firefox ... do you know something where I can have the drag and drop process clearly describe for Chrome ?

Comment: in another hand I saw a great difference between chrome and firefox ... in chrome, the new clas only apply to the img moved(the copy dragged to) and not the img staying in place. In Firefox, the class apply to both img ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found part of the answer for chrome with

```
event.dataTransfer.dropEffect="move";
```

this allow me to test the fact that the new class is correctly apply to the img.

but the area still not work well and don't let me use correctly dragAnDrop actions.